# Movie on alien planet with man shot through tube of breathable liquid

Tags: story-identification, movie

*First of all, no it's not "The Abyss" or "Mission to Mars" (unless I'm really remembering that one wrongly.)*

I can only remember what I'm pretty sure is the ending. Wherein a man in a spacesuit walks to a monolithic structure with a dark backdrop. When inside he talks with a female alien I think (she might have been in a dress.) He is then placed inside a tube, without his suit, that has the breathable liquid and shot through said tube that forms as it goes along.

Possibly 70s, think it was grainy, not quite sure. But I will say I'm trying to remember a movie I watched as a kid around two decades ago.

Comment: You might want to take a look at *Mission to Mars* again.  Once the astronauts (in suits) get inside the face on Mars, they walk into the planetarium where they meet a tall female-looking alien who takes Gary Sinese by the hand, puts him in a transport pod (filled with breathable liquid), and a wormhole-type field spins up around the pod and it is shot towards the aliens' world.

Comment: I did watch the ending part on YouTube, but it didn't match what I was thinking of. What I was thinking of was darker visually and seemed older. So like I said, unless my young brain is remembering wrong or I had a fever dream about it then it was something else.